# What can I use to compare the levels of an independent variable?

Tags: anova

I measured the happiness of my respondents. I used a questionnaire for this which uses a 5-point Likert scale and has 25 items with 5 items measuring each component (5). I want to know which component is the predominant one. What can I use? I was advised to use repeated measures ANOVA which was possible in SPSS. But, I wonder, what could be my IV and DV here? Will the scale scores be the DV and the components my IV?

Comment: Is a component a latent factor which you wish to estimate?

Comment: What does it mean for a component to be predominant?

Comment: The advice to use repeated measures ANOVA would make sense if you are interested in differences in means among groups with repeated measures on the objects of measure. Did you take repeated measurements on each object of measure (i.e. respondent)?

Comment: Often in surveys each question response is potentially dependent on the other responses. You will have to address that question in a way more specific to your data and study design.

Comment: I don't think I understand enough about what you are doing to provide a definitive answer. On the face of it you seem to be interested in a latent factor model with repeated measurements.

Comment: @AgnesianOperator, all respondents answered the same questionnaire making them all have scores for each component (explained by the one who suggested I use repeated measures ANOVA). I want to know if there are significant differences between the components such that component A is significantly higher than B, C, D, and E.